# Using flutter to make create card for UI that begins at very bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a design similar to that in the picture below, where a card begins at the very bottom of the screen. Is there a way to do this formally with flutter?

Right now, moving the card low enough so that it flows over the bottom of the screen works but I am hoping there is a more elegant way to achieve this effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution for this is using a bottom sheet, with showBottomSheet or showModalBottomSheet (documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html)).

You can see two examples in the Flutter gallery:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/persistent_bottom_sheet_demo.dart

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/modal_bottom_sheet_demo.dart

Another alternative is use the bottomSheet property of the Scaffold widget there you can set any Widget that you want.

Comment: Thanks, i am actually trying to make it stay in place (i.e. not a button/swipe up box). Any ideas on how best to do this?

Comment: You can do this with the first example Persistent Bottom Sheet, or you can use a raw BottomSheet widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet/BottomSheet.html.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you've considered this [Align class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 120.0,
    width: 120.0,
    color: Colors.blue[50],
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: FlutterLogo(
        size: 60,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```